# Modal with link to same index

Tags: html, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I have created a modal in which I have placed a `href` link to a contact section placed at the end of the same `index.html`.

When I click the `contact me` button modal dissapears and I am not scrolled down to the contact section (I think that there is some kind of inbuild scrolldown after closing the modal which breaks my own href link).

I tried using javascript method after clicking the button but there also appear problems.
When using `window.location.reload` and then `scrollintoview` to `#kontakt` page reloads nicely but the `scrollintoview` never take place.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle">
  Launch demo modal
</button>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width:50%;margin:auto">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">                
                  <img src="https://www.apacara.com/media/images/orange.jpg" class="d-block w-100"                                              style="width:100%;border-radius:4px;margin:auto">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle6" data-                             bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
                  <a class="btn-grad" href="#kontakt" style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:500!important" data-bs-                        toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Contact me</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-                           bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Previous</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="kontakt" style="margin-top:500px">Helo helo helo helo</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the way event listener works; it only fires one time which is closing the modal.

What I did is just a hack by adding a timeout so the closing of the modal and scrolling to view doesn't fire off at the same time

```js
const myModal = document.getElementById('exampleModalToggle');

myModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
setTimeout(function(){ 
   el = document.querySelector("#kontakt")
   el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}); 
   }, 10);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle">
  Launch demo modal
</button>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width:50%;margin:auto">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">                
                  <img src="https://www.apacara.com/media/images/orange.jpg" class="d-block w-100"                                              style="width:100%;border-radius:4px;margin:auto">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle6" data-                             bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
                  <a class="btn-grad" href="#kontakt" style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:500!important" data-bs-                        toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Contact me</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-                           bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Previous</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="kontakt" style="margin-top:500px">Helo helo helo helo</div>
```

Comment: It scrolls down nicely but the dark background without ability to click still exists. ```<div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>``` this class is remaining on top of body and blocks content.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue, can you try increasing the timeout to 1000ms and try again

Comment: I think the timeout is not the issue since the page is not reloaded. The point is that when the modal is open all of the background becomes unscrollable and darkened out. When you close  the modal the ability to scroll and move on page should come back and the dark background dissapear. However it doesnt happen, only ability to scroll comes back but the dark background and disability to click still appears.

Comment: Is it possible to add to javascript to delete a specific ```div``` without knowing its id ? ```<div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>``` to be exact.

Comment: okay you can remove the "show" from classlist

Comment: Thank you that works. Last thing, how about if I have multiple modals? Should I just copy and paste new listeners or put everything in one?

Comment: You can replicate that as long as they have different IDs